Unset SDKROOT in Ansible
I'm running an Ansible play that is cross-compiling with Xcode on MacOS. When I run printev in my playbook, I see this value:
SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
This is causing my build to fail. I need SDKROOT unset, however any attempts at unsetting it within the playbook aren't successful. This value is not set on the machine itself, only within Ansible. How can I unset this?

As far as I've found, there isn't an elegant way to unset an env var in Ansible. The way I got around this was by invoking unset SDKROOT as part of the shell task that ran my build command. So instead of just make release, I ran unset SDKROOT && make release.
